# Non Repeated Extremly Secure Random Number Generator?

Tags: android, random

I want to genrate 5 digit extremly secure random numbers for some products verifications which should be always unique, their no limits how many times in day or how many times in a week i've to put this request for new generation of manual codes, and it can be in range of 1k - 20k, The main requirement is about to manual codes should have to be always UNIQUE(NON REPEATED) otherwise their would be a big clash.

so please assit me a better and secured way to genrated 5 digit unique codes,
Any recommendations would be very helpful.

for now i am using this reffrence :

```
private static final Random random = new Random();
private static final String CHARS = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567890!@#$";

public static String getToken(int length) {
StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder(length);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    token.append(CHARS.charAt(random.nextInt(CHARS.length())));
}
return token.toString();
}
```

Comment: I don't think "5 digit" and "extremely secure" go together. To make them unique, you had better keep a catalogue of which ones you have already generated.

Comment: actually i have listed all those , but it is very tough job to compare and check all codes manually

Comment: Manually? When you have a computer?

Comment: what is your idea , please tell me , i am eager to know

Comment: Ok, how about using [`HashSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet) to store the used codes.

Comment: well, thanx for your suggestion , i will check possibility's about "HashSet"